# jsbrowser on Raspbian, operating system not supported

Tags: raspberry-pi, jxbrowser

we are trying to run our app that integrates jsbrowser on Raspbian 4.4.50-v7+ (raspberry pi 3) and get the message that the operating system is not installed.
we integrated the linux 32 and 64 bit libraries.
how to get jxbrowser running on Raspbian ?

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi is an ARM-based platform. According to JxBrowser [system requirements](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013733-system-requirements) this platform is not supported at the moment by the JxBrowser library.